# How to run java application on the web?

Tags: java, eclipse

I created a standalone Java application in eclipse(not web application), and 
now i want to run this java program on the web , because it needs to run all the time
and i dont want it to run on my computer.

Can i do it?
Can i upload my java classes or jars to somewhere on the web and it will run it?
(like eclipse run it)?

--Edit--
what is so complicated - how can i put a console java application on the cloud so it can run the main class ( e.g main method : public static void main...) like its run on eclipse.
applet is no good because its run on the user side and not on the cloud.
and in addition i want it to be automatically run without click or enter to a link - like a 
service that run in the backround on the cloud ?

Comment: How is it not a web app, you want it run on the web? Do you have an `applet` you want to run? This question makes no sense.

Comment: I am probably even less sure of what you want than @peeskillet and could benefit from some more details.  What does the app. do?

Comment: Let me be clear - i ment The ability to run an executable JAR, or an java app (by specify the main class ) on JVM host on the internet

Answer (score 3):

Yes, either you can use the [Java Webstart](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/deployment/webstart/)  or you can implement the program as an [Applet](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/deployment/applet/) (given that it has a GUI).

Comment: I have taken care to ensure that the info. pages for [applet](http://stackoverflow.com/tags/applet/info) and [java-web-start](http://stackoverflow.com/tags/java-web-start/info) here at SO, not only link to those pages, but many other handy resources as well.  If you'd like to edit those links into the answer, I can delete this comment as 'noise'.

Comment: If i implement the program as an Applet - the applet will be downloaded to my computer and run on it -  i want it to run on a server or a remote jvm that  can run java application.

Comment: I need the java application to run all the time - in Java Webstart - launch a Java application its by clicking a link in a web page

Answer (score 0):

Make the app an applet (Easiest for putting on the web)